# Modificar variable de session en onclick

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

tengo 2 imagenes , la idea es que al hacer click en un de ellos me guarde en una variable de session la categoria asociada . Busqué información y probé con ajax , pero misteriosamente me devuelve ... código ... no la variable, o sea ... algo está mal . 
El código :
archivo gestionar.php

```html
        function modificarValor(valor){
           var url = 'b_categoria.php';
           $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: {valor},
              success:function(data){
              console.log("Valor Variable : "+ data);
             }
           });
          } 

        <div class="marco_central2">
          <div style="float:left;padding:10px;padding-top:184px;">
              <a href="/ACCE/adelante"  class="reload_link" onclick="modificarValor(1)">
              <?php echo $this->Html->image('menu/HIT-CATEGORIA-2.png'); ?></a>
          </div>
          <div style="float:right;padding:10px;padding-top:184px;">
              <a href="/ELEC/adelante"  class="reload_link" onclick="modificarValor(2)">
              <?php echo $this->Html->image('menu/HIT-CATEGORIA-1.png'); ?></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

archivo b_categoria.php

```html
<?php
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
session_start();

switch ($valor) {
    case 1:
        $_SESSION['categoria_actual'] = "accesorios";
        echo 'Accesorios';
        break;
    case 2:
        $_SESSION['categoria_actual'] = "servicios";
        echo 'Servicios';
    break;
}

?>
```

Aclaro que es una aplicación hecha en cakephp 1.3 muy antigua, que desarrollaron en el lugar donde trabajo .. y hay algunos php encriptados, los desarrolladores desaparecieron hace años. Agradeceré cualquier ayuda !

Comment: Qué código regresa?

Comment: No salió lo que .. regresa html el codigo de una pagina ..

Comment: En ese código html puede estar el error de tu script php o la razón de tu problema, sería útil si agregas la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto al servidor, si la petición te devuelve el mismo html de la página es porque no esta entrando en ninguno de los casos de tu `switch-case`. Puede ser porque el valor contenido en tu variable `$valor` este siendo tratado como un `string` en vez de `integer` que es lo que estas tratando de comparar en el `switch`.

Haz un `var_dump($valor)` y asegurate qué contiene tu variable y de qué tipo es antes de hacer cualquier comparación posterior. Si solo necesitas trabajar con numeros enteros, intenta [parsear el valor a numero entero](http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php) para proceder de ser necesario.

Por último, añade un `default` a tu `switch-case` para enviar una respuesta por defecto si ninguno de los valores coincide con tu comparación. Nuestro trabajo como programadores también consiste en abarcar el mayor número de casos posibles para prevenir comportamientos indeseados.

En cuanto al cliente; añade el callback de error a tu petición ajax por que no siempre todo es color de rosa:

```
success: function() { ... },
error: function(err) { console.error(err) }
```

Revisa bien como estás enviando los datos de la petición, si te fijas bien en la función que contiene el ajax, en cuestiones de ecmascript5, estás pasando un valor erroneo al parámetro `data`; `data: {valor}`.

Usa JSON como estándar en cada petición que hagas, tanto del lado del servidor como del cliente, agrega los parámetros `contentType: 'application/json'` y `dataType: 'json'` para asegurarte de ello.

Revisa desde tu navegador el estado de la petición cuando entra y sale, fijate como se están enviando los datos y qué respuesta estás recibiendo del servidor.

Es cuestión de debuguear y analizar, tarde o temprano le encuentras el chiste.